# How to interpret inverse transformations estimates in linear regression?

Tags: parameters, linear-regression, transformation, interpretation, inverse-transform

I'm planning to perform linear regression with hemoglobin levels as outcome and age, bmi, race, income as predictors. As the residuals did not follow normal distribution I performed log and square root transformations which are not helpful. So, I performed inverse transformations and the assumptions are met. How to interpret the following estimates? Age 0.00032918 Income 5.297891E-8

Thanks for the help in advance!

I thought of interpreting it as "For a one-unit increase in Age, the reciprocal Hb levels is expected to change by 0.00032918 units, assuming all other variables are held constant. But, it is not making sense.